# I"m trying to access google storage with url in ionic but the image wont load

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-storage

I have some images in my google cloud storage. the bucket is public.
When I try to access the image from ionic in the browser the image is shown But when I run my app on devapp or even on the browser of the tablet the image Just won't show. Does anyone have a solution for me???

Comment: Do you have some example code? It would be helpful to reproduce.

Comment: <img  [src]="item.image.URL" />  the image url is this: "https://storage.cloud.google.com/wordproject/Animals0.jpg". You can make sure that this url is good.

Comment: why do you have [src]= instead of src= ? You can check correct tam syntax:  
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp. Also, please edit your question to include example code.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you shared is indeed publicly accessible. However, the issue you’re experiencing might be coming from your **cross-origin resource sharing configuration** (CORS).

CORS is a mechanism that allows interactions between resources from different origins, which is normally prohibited in order to prevent malicious behavior.

Please see the following [**link**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#configure-cors-bucket) to configure CORS on your bucket that stores the images and try accessing them through you app again.

For more information on handling CORS issues in **Ionic** I'd also recommend you to review this [**article**](https://ionicframework.com/blog/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/), which is the official documentation of Ionic.

Let me know if it helps.